# alpine latest image gives /usr/local/bin/start-server: line 28: php-fpm7: not found error

Tags: php, docker, nginx, moodle, alpine-linux

I am working on moodle development with docker. Because of the latest verion of of moodle that has a version mismatch with php7, I need to use php8 or more.

In one part of the dockerfile, the code is:

```
# ---------------------
# Main moodle runtime environment, using nginx and php7
# ---------------------
FROM alpine:latest

# user is hard coded in php/php-fpm.d/www.conf - when changing ENV, keep this in mind
ENV USER=moodle
ENV UID=12345
ENV GID=23456

# based on https://docs.moodle.org/400/de/PHP - there are a few missing and some of them can not be installed
RUN apk add --update-cache \
  php\
    nginx \
    php-fpm \
    #php-iconv \
    php-mbstring \
    php-curl \
    php-openssl \
    php-tokenizer \
    #php-xmlrpc \
    php-xmlreader \
    php-fileinfo \
    php-soap \
    #php-ctype \
    php-zip \
    php-gd \
    php-session \
    php-simplexml \
#    php-spl \
#    php-pcre \
    php-dom \
    php-xml \
    php-intl \
    php-json \
    php-mysqli \
    php-sodium \
    php-exif \
    #php-pecl-redis \
 # helper for running moodle cron jobs from cli:
    fcgi \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN apk --no-cache add php-mbstring php-iconv
# fix work iconv library with alphine
RUN apk add --no-cache --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/ --allow-untrusted gnu-libiconv
ENV LD_PRELOAD /usr/lib/preloadable_libiconv.so php

RUN apk --no-cache add php-mbstring php-iconv
# Installieren Sie den Nginx-Webserver und eine Liste der erforderlichen Pakete.
# PHP setting max_input_vars is recommended to be >= 5000 for PHP 7.x installations. It's a requirement for PHP 8.x installations. For further details, see Environment - max input vars.




WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html



COPY config-default.php /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY nginx /etc/nginx
COPY php /etc/php7



#some more codes...


COPY cron/moodle /etc/periodic/1min/
RUN echo "*       *       *       *       *       run-parts /etc/periodic/1min" >> /etc/crontabs/root && \
    chmod +x /etc/periodic/1min/moodle && \
    crontab -l

RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log && \
      ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log && \
    ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/moodle-cron




EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

STOPSIGNAL SIGTERM

CMD /usr/bin/php-fpm7 -D; /usr/local/bin/start-server
```

When I build it, I get this error:

```
/usr/local/bin/start-server: line 28: php-fpm7: not found
```

whcich basically refers to the last line. I studied and found that start-server expects php-form7. If I were to use an older moodle version and php7, this error would not occur.

I wonder what is the solution here.

Comment: Instead of adding PHP to Alpine I recommend to use the official PHP base image: https://hub.docker.com/_/php

Comment: Yes I thought about it, but i also need to run apk add nginx, etc. for these I cannot use php image, can i?

Comment: Sure, you can add anything that is not already present in the selected base image.  Note that `apk` (Alpine Package Keeper) is available in Alpine-based images only (like `php:8.2.9-alpine`).  For Debian-based images the package manager is `apt-get`.

Comment: Hi @Pino, I followed your instructions. with php:...alpine. It solved some of my problems, like the one above, but it the build runs forever. I also asked in docker forum: https://forums.docker.com/t/moodle-docker-building-for-infinite-time-not-showing-any-error-too/137385 (hope stack overflow or you won't mind me pasting the link). I wonder if you know something about it